# Libgdx game slower and slower on restart

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, libgdx

I'm testing my game and I've encountered a problem. My main game class is restarting (not the whole application) when the user dies, but whenever it restarts, it just runs slower and slower. I'm thinking of a possible memory leak.

I'm switching over from a screen to screen with setScreen(Screen sc) method. I'm also cleaning up in dispose() method, and I can't find the reason.

So I'm asking you to maybe point me in any direction what could be causing my app to slow down on the restart?

It might be ShapeRenderer since I'm rendering a huge amount of shapes in loops- maybe that's the problem? But the app works perfect unill I call a new instance of the main game class.

There is too much code to post it, so I'm sorry for the huge amount of text. I really hope you could somehow point me what could be wrong!

Comment: Post the code related to what happens when the player dies somewhere or upload the entire thing to github. Two possiblities, either you introduced a memoryleak or libgdx did, we can't know without code.

Comment: one of the reason for this can be static variables. as class is still loaded in memory when u close the app but not killed it yet

Comment: Are you using box 2d in your game

Comment: No I wasn't using box2d because i didn't find it necessary. I uploaded my source code to https://github.com/learnacc/libgdx-learning , I probably did many things wrong since I'm really a noob in graphics, and any advice on how to fix the slow performance would be helpful. Thank you all!

Comment: Make sure you're disposing of any assets, arrays, images, fonts etc in the `hide()` method within your game screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something that might help you.
Use jmap ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html ). jmap displays you which instances of objects are currently held by the jvm. Just make a runnable jar of your game, start the game, check jmap, die a bit and then check jmap again. Maybe you see an increase in Texture-Objects thus you might not be cleaning up some of those ( it is easy to forget some if you are using an AssetManager).

Comment: I've tried Memory Analyzer from eclipse, but I memory consumption is apparently not so high at all, barely 10-20 mb. It's really weird because the speeds the game is working at come so random. Even sometimes after already playing (when I could expect slow performance) it suddenly just starts working super smooth. Does it help anything if I tell you I've noticed FPS randomly changing?

Comment: I just looked at your code and while your Kurve-class-code seems to be disposing all its ressources correctly, your ScoreScreen class doesn't dispose it texture or spritebatch at all. I ran the programm ( after adding some random textures ;) ) and used the fps-logger to show the fps and it is running at about 60frames, with little drops when the screen is changing.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [ScoreScreen](https://github.com/learnacc/libgdx-learning/blob/master/Kurve/src/com/me/Screens/ScoreScreen.java) you will see that you are not disposing of the Texture you load.

I would highly suggest you take a look at the [Asset Manager](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager) tutorials and guides for libgdx to avoid this in the future.

Edit:

Side note, your code isn't bad at all so don't be ashamed by it. In fact I would say its better than average :).

Comment: I study math and I'm ashamed for this one, sorry for all your time, I've pretty much messed up a very basic algebraic formula and it seemed, but never thought I could be wrong on that. I'm really sorry guys but thanks for I've been forced today to learn about encountering memory leaks! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using a tool that tracks memory allocations will be far more useful than a code review.

Use the Eclipse DDMS memory tracker: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc